# Translate ">" in XML RDF Triple

Tags: json, xml, special-characters, rdf, triples

I have JSON String value `>` which is a special character in XML.

After the data ingestion, the XML String becomes `\u003e`.

How can I preserve `>` in the XML String?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XML escaped characters

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

This post might help you with more info [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, `>` is fine as itself in XML.  See [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085) for details.

> After the data ingestion, the XML String becomes `\u003e`.
>
> How can I preserve `>` in the XML String?

How to preserve a character through a translation depends entirely on the translation.  You've said specified nothing more than "data ingestion".  It can be a challenge to identify and remedy a poor translation of a *known* program; doing so for an *unknown* program is impossible.

Your question is unanswerable as it currently stands.